# How to justify text in Firefox and Safari with CSS?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, justify

In Chrome, on a paragraph element,

```
text-align: justify;
```

works fine and creates a block alignment, but has no effect in Firefox or Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: This will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Browser_compatibility

Comment: IE doesn't know `unset`. Use with caution.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `white-space` property to `pre-line`. It will force to collapse into a single whitespace and the text will wrap on line breaks. This will help to block align:

```
   white-space: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Posting in behalf of the OP who posted the answer in comment*

I believe I solved the problem:

```
 white-space: pre-wrap;
```

was interfering so I used

```
white-space: unset;
```

to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On paragraph element or `<p>` is block label element but **DTD** says it's contain inline element. If `text-align: justify` not working you have to check your browser user agent stylesheet. If `p` is `display: block / inline-block;` then `text-align: justify;` will work.

```
P{
    display: block; /* inline-block; */
    text-align: justify;
}
```

It will solve your Firefox and Safari issue.